# When was an open face helmet used for the last time in open-wheel car racing?

Tags: equipment, formula-1

As for Formula 1, the last time an open face helmet was used was during the 1974 Swedish GP by Leo Kinnunen, and the last time it's been used during an official F1 weekend was at the 1975 Monaco GP by Carlos Reutemann

But what about other open-wheel car racing categories, like IndyCar/CART, F2, F3000, and such?

I can't find any information on this topic

Comment: This question is very broad as it currently reads, as there is no other criteria to meet besides being an open-wheel category. If you can limit the range of competitions and races that needs to be considered, this will enable answers that are more reliable and source-able.